# What is the easiest way to connect to Wifi with Debian-Linux OS and the command line interface (no GUI)?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, command-line, debian, python

I installed Debian/Linux on my laptop and it doesn't have a GUI. I have been playing with python3 that came with my installation of the OS and I would like to do pip installs for more python packages such as matplotlib but at the moment my laptop is not connected to wifi and the commands I have tried from other resources gets error messages that the commands don't exist.

Ideally there is a simple one liner for the shell like :

`user@debian:~$ connect.wifi("wifi name")`
or maybe a python package i could call

`>>>open(connect_to_wifi.py)`

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner will be pretty hard initially. Usually i use the following guide for setup. Ofc. you can write a script that does most of the stuff for you, but in general this guide should be sufficient.

Please note, that you can use the information provided to try and write your own script + ask for help in case it doesn't work, but SuperUser in general is here to help if you hit a dead end and not a "from scratch" script-writing service :)

[Link to Manual](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-cli-on-debian-10-buster#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20Connect%20To%20WiFi%20From%20the,Config.%20WPA_Supplicant%20can%20generate%20its%20own...%20More%20)